# Gradient markup with Gspread Formatting

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am using Gspread Formatting to set background color to cells in Google Sheets.
Now I want to use the GradientRule to accomplish this:

[Conditional formatting with GradientRule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkky.png)

I know I have to set a "minpoint" and a "maxpoint", but I am not sure how to do this.

This is what I got so far:

```
def color():
spr = client.open("Kleurtjes")
sheet = spr.worksheet("Tab3")

rule = ConditionalFormatRule(

    ranges=[GridRange.from_a1_range('A1:A10', sheet)],

    GradientRule=GradientRule(
        minpoint(format=CellFormat(backgroundColor=Color(255,255,255)), type='number'),
        maxpoint(format=CellFormat(backgroundColor=Color(0,128,0)), type='number')
    )
    )

rules = get_conditional_format_rules(sheet)
rules.append(rule)
rules.save()
```

Can you help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to achieve the following situation. (The image is from your question.)

  [image]

#### Modification points:

- You can see the script of `GradientRule()` and `InterpolationPoint()` at [here](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting/blob/bdd440fdae4e6f93dbc30b5b765d25105eb96512/gspread_formatting/conditionals.py#L216) and [here](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting/blob/bdd440fdae4e6f93dbc30b5b765d25105eb96512/gspread_formatting/conditionals.py#L203), respectively.
- At `ConditionalFormatRule()`, it seems that the AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest of the batchUpdate method in Sheets API is used. In this case, the color is required to be set from `0` to `1`. Please be careful this.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
rule = ConditionalFormatRule(

    ranges=[GridRange.from_a1_range('A1:A10', sheet)],

    GradientRule=GradientRule(
        minpoint(format=CellFormat(backgroundColor=Color(255,255,255)), type='number'),
        maxpoint(format=CellFormat(backgroundColor=Color(0,128,0)), type='number')
    )
    )
```

To:

```
rule = ConditionalFormatRule(
    ranges=[GridRange.from_a1_range('A1:A10', sheet)],
    gradientRule=GradientRule(
        maxpoint=InterpolationPoint(color=Color(1, 1, 1), type='MAX'),
        minpoint=InterpolationPoint(color=Color(0, 128 / 255, 0), type='MIN')
    )
)
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet by using Sheets API with gspread and gspread_formatting. Please be careful this.
- When you want to achieve the colors of above your image, for example, how about `minpoint=InterpolationPoint(color=Color(0.34117648, 0.73333335, 0.5411765), type='MIN')`?

#### References:

- [AddConditionalFormatRuleRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addconditionalformatrulerequest)
- [Color](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color)
- [gspread-formatting](https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting)

Comment: Wauw, you are amazing.. works perfectly. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @Kuzco Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tenaike Just checking. 0, 128 / 255, 0 does not seem to be RGB? What color scheme is it you are using?

For example, if I use 1,1,1 it is white in Google Sheets while it should be black in RGB.

Comment: @Kuzco I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About your 2nd question, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about the result you expect. But, about the color for using this request, you can see [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color). For example, when `R`, `G` and `B` are `255, 255, 255`, this request is required to use `255/255, 255/255, 255/255` which is `1, 1, 1`. If I misunderstood your 2nd question and that official document was not useful for your situation, I apologize again.

Comment: @Kuzco About `For example, if I use 1,1,1 it is white in Google Sheets while it should be black in RGB.`, in my environment, as a test situation, when I tested `1, 1, 1` for `red, green, blue` to the background color of cell, the white background was obtained. When `0, 0, 0` was used, the black background was obtained. I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: chiming in to thank you for this 2 years later haha